# Vector que muestre numeros de otro vector sin repetirlos?

Tags: c++

Necesito hacer un vector en base a otro. El vector base puede ser por ejemplo: [2 4 7 9 3 3 1 4 8]
y el otro vector debe de mostrar los numeros de ese vector en el orden que aparecen pero sin repetirlos, osea deberia de quedar:[2 4 7 9 3 1 8]

Esto se hace en c++, intente hacerlo recorriendo el vector con:

```
for(int i=0; i<20; i++)
 if(v[i+1]!=v[i])
 numero[i]=v[i];
```

donde v es el vector base y numero el vector resultante, intente hacer la condición: si el numero de la siguiente posicion del vector base es diferente al anterior, asi los vaya poniendo en el vector resultante, pero pues no he logrado hacerlo, agradezco la ayuda que me puedan dar.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes hacer uso de algunos de los contenedores que trae de serie C++:

- `std::vector`: Contenedor por defecto. Almacena una cantidad aleatoria de valores conservando su orden
- `std::set`: Contenedor que no admite duplicados. Los registros aparecen ordenados

Haciendo uso de ambos contenedores podemos implementar el algoritmo de la siguiente manera:

```
std::vector<int> numeros = { 2, 4, 7, 9, 3, 3, 1, 4, 8 };
std::set<int> registro;

std::vector<int> sin_repeticiones;

for (int numero : numeros)
{
    auto [_, ok] = registro.insert(numero);
    if (ok)
    {
        sin_repeticiones.push_back(numero);
    }
}

std::cout << "Numeros sin repeticiones:\n";
for (int numero : sin_repeticiones)
{
    std::cout << numero << ' ';
}
std::cout << '\n';
```

Lo que hacemos es tratar de añadir los números al contenedor `set`. Este contenedor nos indica si el número se ha añadido de forma efectiva o si, por el contrario, ya se encontraba presente.

De hecho `registro.insert(numero)` lo que hace es devolver una tupla (dos valores):

- Iterador que apunta al elemento
- Un booleano que indica si el elemento es nuevo o no.

Lo que con hacemos entonces es `auto [_, ok] = registro.insert(numero);` es *explotar* esa tupla para extraer sus elementos. El iterador no nos interesa (lo almacenamos en una variable con nombre `_`), pero el booleano sí, este valor lo usaremos para determinar si añadimos el número al vector final o no.

Esta sintaxis es propia de C++17. Podemos migrarlo facilmente a versiones anteriores de este lenguaje:

**C++11 y C++14**

```
bool ok;
std::tie(std::ignore, ok) = registro.insert(numero);
```

**Pre C++11**

```
bool ok = registro.insert(numero).second;
```

Answer (score 1):

Usa `std::copy_if` usando como predicado una función que busque el número a insertar en la lista de números ya insertados:

```
std::vector<int> origen{2, 4, 7, 9, 3, 3, 1, 4, 8};
std::vector<int> destino{};

std::copy_if(origen.begin(), origen.end(), std::back_inserter(destino),
    [&destino](int v){ return std::find(destino.begin(), destino.end(), v) == destino.end(); });
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU/9asMgEP87PsVBoY3gCvuArUnaFxmjWGMyWapBL8IIefZME0s3GIhwv8870fcPouO6neeN0qIbagmVMg6t5NcTuWNeCjT2N8K71liFn0FGlEa4cqVzSkaSOayLYjVUgTlB0LVSj08MXhi8MjgweF7e44K8TeU/plo6VNqMgUysMP33WTX5Gre/yDY2shS/l7qO0yK9cPF1VtpJi9LmKYoykmXv2zR95HFrT0ewEgerV2OjQkpS3BtuQKrwFI7Hv2AJE42LNsZCLox2CHxAA1sPxU1JQ306ZECoKvDx28GuJNM8/wA)</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Se incluyen las librerías

```
#include <iostream>
```

Esta función retorna si un valor existe dentro de un vector

```
bool exist(int num, int v[9], int end){
    for(int i=0; i<end; i++){
        if(v[i]== num){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Función principal que llena el vector sin números repetidos y los muestra

```
int main() {

    int v1[9] = {2, 4, 7, 9, 3, 3, 1, 4, 8};
    int v2[9];
    int count=0;
    
    for(int i=0; i<9; i++){
       //count va ha ser siempre el tamaño actual del vector
        if(!exist(v1[i],v2, count)){
            v2[count]=v1[i];
            count ++;
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i<count; i++){
        std::cout << v2[i] << " ";
    }
        
}
```

Esta solución del problema se puede decir que utiliza la técnica de divide y vencerás que consiste en dividir el problema en problemas más "pequeños" (más simples de resolver), esto se hace al crear un método aparte que determina si un número se encuentra o no en el vector

Comment: La pregunta es sobre C++, no sobre C. Tendria que usar `constexpr` en lugar de `#define`, `std::cout` en lugar de `printf`, y `std::array` en lugar de arrays estilo C. Ademas de que el codigo en C no compila, ya que C no tiene el primitivo `bool`, asi que tienes que incluir `stdbool.h` para que funcione.

Comment: @Pablochaches, La pregunta esta en C++, no en C, ya corregí la solución